# How to lock write permissions on NFC tags? Any tools out there?

Tags: android, nfc

I just finished building my android app that reads NFC tags. I've been writing the tags using the Nfc-Eclipse-Plugin. The plugin works great, but there is no way to lock the tag once the tag is written.

Are they any tools out there that let me customize the records I want on the tag, and then lock the tag when I've written it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the [NFC Developer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antares.nfc) app of the [NFC Eclipes plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) to include a 'burn mode' - it can be enabled from the options menu once an NDEF payload has been loaded. Please give it (version 1.3) a try!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [TagWriter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter). Switch to "Pro" mode in the preferences (option "Switch UI mode"), then you will get an additional menu option "Tools" that contains functions such as marking the NDEF message on a tag as read-only and locking a tag.

It depends on the kind of tag whether it can be locked or not. Beware that, depending on the kind of tag, marking the NDEF message as read-only sometimes cannot be undone (this is the case with a NFC Forum Type 2 Tag, such as MIFARE Ultralight). Locking a tag can usually not be undone either (for example Type 2 Tag or ICODE tag).

Comment: Type1 tags an also be locked down.

Comment: Yes, according to the spec, although details on locking for the ones with Dynamic Memory config are fuzzy. All Type 1 Tags that I have seen in the wild have their own lock bits locked, so they could not be changed.

Comment: Strange, it works well with all dynamic Type1 tags that I have in my office.

Comment: Just to be clear: do you mean setting the NDEF message in the Capability Container bytes to R/O or do you mean actually locking all the memory blocks that contain the NDEF message data?

Comment: Using the OTP bits, and lock the written content. Works very well for me.