# Change NFC tag to be read only

Tags: android, nfc

Currently I am using the following app to write data into a NFC tag, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antares.nfc&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbnRhcmVzLm5mYyJd ,as it allows me to specify the AAR of the tag. However, when I am writing the tag, I have found out an security issue, the data in the tag can be changed easily, therefore I would like to ask if it is possible to specific only some people can re-write the tag? Or in a simple way, lock the tag, so nobody can rewrite it after I am sure the data in the app is correct. I am still a beginner of using the NFC technology, and find it may become more popular in the future, therefore I would like to learn more about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing you own application; If the tag is already Ndef formatted, you have the Ndef.makeReadOnly() method, which you can apply after you have done Ndef.writeNdefMessage(NdefMessage). Or if the tag is not Ndef formatted but is NdefFormatable you have the method NdefFormatable.makeReadOnly(NdefMessage), which Ndef formats the tag, writes the NdefMessage and makes the tag Read Only all in one go.

There are also other NFC applications in the Play Store which will make an already written tag read only, if the tag technology allows. But this is a programming/development site.

Comment: okay, thank you for your helping, I am sorry I post the question in a wrong site.

Comment: I don't think this is the wrong site, actually. See for example these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456482/how-to-lock-write-permissions-on-nfc-tags-any-tools-out-there and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875393/nfc-tag-with-user-authentication