# Locking a segment within an NFC tag

Tags: android, locking, nfc, readonly, ndef

Is it possible to lock a specific segment within an NFC tag so it would be READ-ONLY, whereas the remaining segments would still be writable? I want to assure that specific data on the tag cannot be overwritten once imprinted, yet I want the tag to remain writable for other data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change NFC tag to be read only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896981/change-nfc-tag-to-be-read-only)

Comment: Thank you, I refined my question.

Comment: That will work with mifare classic

Answer (score 1):

When the data is NDEF formatted, and a part of the data is set to read only, you loose the capability to write the data again (i.e. updating) with writeNdefMessage().

Is that correct, or is there a way to set a part of a NDEF message read only, but to update the rest later (other than by low level commands)?

(Edit: Sorry, this should have been a comment to NFC Guys's answer, not an answer on its own)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but it depends on the specific tag that you are using. For example, some well-known and commonly used tags such as MIFARE Classic, MIFARE Ultralight, NTAG203, NTAG21x and various NfcV tags (ISO 15693 compatible, e.g. ICODE SLI tags) all allow this.
However, you will have to write the code yourself to actually configure the tags to your liking. Android does not provide specific functionality, because the commands that need to be sent to the tag are usually not standardized (you need to the datasheet or the manual for the tag type you are using).