# React Native (not Expo): Set and Verify Password on NTAG216 with `react-native-nfc-manager`

Tags: android, react-native, nfc, react-native-nfc-manager

I'm building a React Native app (not using Expo) that interacts with NXP NTAG216 NFC tags. I'm successfully using `react-native-nfc-manager` to read and write data, but I'm struggling to implement password protection for write operations

**Key Challenges:**

- **I can't find a straightforward way to set and verify passwords using this library.**

**Specific Questions:**

1. **Is it possible to directly set and verify password protection on NTAG216 tags with `react-native-nfc-manager`?** If so, what specific methods or approach does the library offer?
2. **If `react-native-nfc-manager` doesn't support password protection, are there alternative libraries or strategies I can explore?** I'm open to using custom commands or lower-level communication if necessary.

Code Snippets:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import NfcManager, {Ndef, NfcTech, nfcManager} from 'react-native-nfc-manager';

// Pre-step, call this before any NFC operations
NfcManager.start();

function App() {
  async function readNdef() {
    try {
      console.log(' ~ readNdef ~ NfcManager:', 'entered');
      // register for the NFC tag with NDEF in it
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);
      // the resolved tag object will contain `ndefMessage` property
      const tag = await NfcManager.getTag();
      console.warn('Tag found', tag);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn('Oops!', ex);
    } finally {
      // stop the nfc scanning
      console.log('exited');
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    }
  }
  function buildUrlPayload(valueToWrite) {
    return Ndef.encodeMessage([Ndef.uriRecord(valueToWrite)]);
  }
  const writeNFC = async () => {
    let result = false;

    try {
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);
      const bytes = buildUrlPayload(
        'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896981/change-nfc-tag-to-be-read-only',
      );
      await NfcManager.ndefHandler.writeNdefMessage(bytes);
      console.log(' ~ writeNFC ~ bytes:', bytes);
      console.log('makeReadOnly');
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn(ex);
    } finally {
      console.log('eixt write');
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    }

    return result;
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={readNdef}>
        <Text>Scan a Tag</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={writeNFC}>
        <Text style={{color: 'grey'}}>Write Tag</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

**Version Information:**

- Node.js version: `v18.17.1`
- React version: `18.2.0`
- React Native version: `0.73.4`
- `react-native-nfc-manager` version: `3.14.12`

**NFC Tag Infomation:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCKMB.jpg)

**Desired Outcome:**
Understand how to implement password protection on NTAG216 tags in my React Native app, either with react-native-nfc-manager or an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some answers

Q1) Yes it is possible set and verify a password with react-native-nfc-manager

Q2) Password setting is not part of the NFC standards, various Tag hardware families each tend to have a different way of implementing password protection, so you have to interact with the Tag's at a lower level than the Ndef Data format. It's unlikely for other libraries to support it direct other than at a lower level that react-native-nfc-manager can also use.

So some background reading first, you should read and understand the Ntag21x's [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf), specifically Section 8.8 and 10.7

Your code need to access the Tag at the NfcA level.

so code something like

```
await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.NfcA);
// Build a byte array to send to Tag
const commandBytes = [162,...,...]
const responceBytes = await NfcManager.NfcAHandler.transceive(commandBytes)
// Check response
// Repeat until all the necessary commands are sent
```

The general set of command to set a password are defined in the datasheet and are platform independent and the are a number of stackoverflow question about password setting like https://stackoverflow.com/a/63259021/2373819